# Pycassa: how to query parts of a Composite Type

Tags: cassandra, pycassa

Basically I'm asking the same thing as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054882/hector-how-to-query-parts-of-a-composite-type) but for the Python Cassandra library, PyCassa.

Lets say you have a composite type storing data like this:

```
[20120228:finalscore] = '31-17'
[20120228:halftimescore]= '17-17'
[20120221:finalscore] = '3-14'
[20120221:halftimescore]= '3-0'
[20120216:finalscore] = '54-0'
[20120216:halftimescore]= '42-0'
```

So, I know I can easily slice based off of the first part of the composite type by doing:

```
>>> cf.get('1234', column_start('20120216',), column_finish('20120221',))
OrderedDict([((u'20120216', u'finalscore'), u'54-0'),
((u'20120216', u'halftimescore'), u'42-0')])
```

But if I only want the finalscore, I would assume I could do:

```
>>> cf.get('1234', column_start('20120216', 'finalscore'),
column_finish('20120221', 'finalscore'))
```

To get:

```
OrderedDict([((u'20120216', u'finalscore'), u'54-0')])
```

But instead, I get:

```
OrderedDict([((u'20120216', u'finalscore'), u'54-0'),
((u'20120216', u'halftimescore'), u'42-0')])
```

Same as the 1st call.

Am I doing something wrong? Should this work? Or is there some syntax using the cf.get(... columns=[('20120216', 'finalscore')]) ? I tried that too and got an exception.

According to http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/introduction-to-composite-columns-part-1, I should be able to do something like this...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If know all the components of the composite column then you should the `'columns'` option:

```
cf.get('1234', columns=[('20120216', 'finalscore')])
```

You said you got an error trying to do this, but I would suggest trying again. It works fine for me.

When you are slicing composite columns you need to think about how they are sorted. Composite columns sort starting first with the left most component, and then sorting each component toward the right. So In your example the columns would look like this:

```
+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+----------------+
| 20120216   | 20120216      | 20120221   | 20120221      | 20120228   | 20120228       |
| finalscore | halftimescore | finalscore | halftimescore | finalscore | halftimescore  |
+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+----------------+
```

Thus when you slice from `('20120216', 'finalscore')` to `('20120221', 'finalscore')` you get both values for `'20120216'`. To make your query work as you want it to you could change the column_finish to `('20120216', 'halftimescore')`.

Comment: Ok so you're right on the cf.get() call, that works correctly, I must have typed something wrong.

Comment: But regarding the second part of my question, I think my example was a little poor, because what I'm really looking for is how to query for a partial-composite in Pycassa.

Clearly in both Hector and Pycassa, one can perform a Slice Query using a partial-composite, like so:

cf.get('1234', column_start=('20120216',), column_finish=('20120221',))

But I get an error when I try to do a cf.get() using a partial-composite. Is that not possible in Cassandra?

Comment: A partial composite can only be used for slicing. When you use get you have to know the complete names of the columns you want.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much.

So generally if you need to filter out data based on one of the sub-types of your composite, either your application code needs to take care of it or you need to re-organize the order of the components of your composite?

Comment: @stantonk regarding partial-composites for slice ends, you definitely should be able to do that (in pycassa 1.4.0 or later). How is it breaking for you?

Comment: It is working, I misunderstood what was possible with slicing on partial-composites as a result of the datastax example.